# Webpack dev-server doesn't show the inline image

Tags: image, webpack

I'm trying to understand how webpack is working. For this I created a very simple example:

**Folder structure**

[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="../src/images/lion.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see the index.html is inside the **dist** folder. If I open the index.html in browser, it shows the images. 
But if I run the **dev-server**, it starts the browser, shows the index.html but cannot find the image.
And the console shows this error:
[image]

Does any one know why webpack cannot show the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `html-loader` https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/ so that it `require()`s for you every `url` from `<img src="<url>">` correctly at compile time, otherwise your browser will try to access the path it cannot reach during runtime.

Also when using `html-loader`, since it will require `img` urls for you, you will need a specific loader that understands image format, for which you can use https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/ or https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Otherwise you will need to copy all your images to a dist folder where you can access them publicly during runtime in browser from your html without `html-loader` or `require` calls. But the copying itself can be done again through another loader https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ .

And still you cannot access the compile level paths like `../src`, since when webpack is running it's compiling everything into a final public folder where you only have your main js file and all of it's `require()`ed dependencies that are put into the same final(`dist`) folder based on the rules from `loaders` or `plugins` property in webpack config.

Comment: I thought that a loader is only needed for background images, but not for inline images. I mean the image is inside the static index.html and the path to it is unchanged. But I still need a loader?

Comment: Thanks. I understand that webpack can only see the files and folders inside the dist folder. It cannot see or access any other files and folder, which are outside of the dist folder. If you want webpack to do so, you will need to use html and other loaders. Right?

Comment: The raw html file when executed in the browser will try to access `../src` from img url and will find nothing. Since the html file is itself on the root path level from browser standpoint. So all your files that you want to be accessible should reside in the public dist folder that you form after compiling your source files with webpack. So you need to somehow transform your html img src attribute to point to a correct image file address from the root of your website during compilation time with webpack, so when the `dist` is formed and you open the page you get the resolution correctly.

Comment: And the only way to do it is to somehow inform webpack about the urls in the html, but to do that you first need to inform webpack about html itself, since the only thing webpack understand by default is only javascript/json. And the only way to teach webpack about how to handle html or html urls is through loaders, that will eventually parse the html, extract urls wrap them in `require()` calls for you, and trigger all other chains of loaders that will handle the required resources with behaviors that you set up in your webpack config